# C# Excel not creating an instance when run outside of debug mode. (IIS instance)

Tags: c#, excel, dataset

Sorry for the poorly worded title. I have an application that will take in an excel file, make some changes, format the data as a dataset and export to excel in C#. when I run either in debug mode (F5) or with ctrl + F5 it has no problem running. The excel sheet is created, filled, and saved to the proper location. when I set up in instance in IIS to test it outside of this method to simulate a user (same machine, browser, etc), it cannot create the excel application. It does not throw an error, it just simply never creates, fills, or moves to location and then says everything worked. I believe the problem (to the best of my knowledge) is with the code here

```
 Excel.Application excelApp = new Excel.Application();
 excelApp.Visible = true;
```

To clarify, my excel import at the top is

```
 using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
```

This problem is hard to understand without an error output. The best information I can provide is what is provided in event viewer.

In the System View I get an error of

```
 The server {00024500-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} did not register with DCOM within the required timeout.
```

And in the Application Viewer I get an error of

```
 Faulting application name: EXCEL.EXE, version: 16.0.9126.2282, time stamp: 0x5b90650a
 Faulting module name: AppVIsvSubsystems32.dll, version: 6.3.9600.18895, time stamp: 0x5a4b127e
 Exception code: 0xc0000142
 Fault offset: 0x0009d4e2
 Faulting process id: 0x13a4
 Faulting application start time: 0x01d45984c26a7014
 Faulting application path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Root\Office16\EXCEL.EXE
 Faulting module path: AppVIsvSubsystems32.dll
 Report Id: 001becbd-c578-11e8-80f3-00505689c70f
 Faulting package full name: 
 Faulting package-relative application ID:
```

Let me know if anymore information is needed or if anything was unclear

Comment: Does your IIS instance run on the same machine as where you made the debug?

Comment: Yes, same machine.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you need to use a different library to zip. [EPPlus](https://www.nuget.org/packages/EPPlus/)

Comment: What is the reasoning for needing to use a different library to zip?

Comment: @Nick The name is on the library :) to make your job easier.

Comment: @Nick and you don't need to deal with such mistakes.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is the "correct" solution, but this solution did work after implementing EPPlus. For that reason i'll mark this as the solution.

Comment: @Nick you can be sure. Because libraries can handle such thin and small things for you. Otherwise you have to deal with too many settings.

Answer (score 0):

Try without using interop, and using dynamic variable instead:

```
Type excelType = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("Excel.Application");
dynamic excelApp = Activator.CreateInstance(excelType);
excelApp.Visible = true;
```

Comment: I don't use dynamic almost ever so perhaps I made a mistake, but when adding that I got an error saying

     'System.Reflection.TypeInfo' does not contain a definition for 'Visible'

Comment: Yes Excel is installed.

Comment: Sorry I missed a step!